# How to drop all unnecessary UDP traffic on INPUT chain?

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, udp, tor

About 2 weeks ago, I started running a Tor relay, which itself operates solely on TCP.

So, I would like to drop all UDP packets, which are unneeded.

But I don't know, what is actually needed (if anything).

My firewall looks like this after about 1 day of uptime - **beware not to comment or answer on behalf of my TCP protection rules**, I am just doing some personal research:

```
iptables -L -v --line-numbers

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 17862 packets, 1945K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             u32 ! "0x4&0x3fff=0x0" /* ICMP fragmented packets */
2        0     0 DROP       icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             length 1492:65535 /* ICMP oversized unfragmented packets */
3        1  1500 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE /* NULL scan */
4        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG /* Xmas scan */
5        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,PSH,URG /* stealth scan */
6        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG /* pscan 1 */
7        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN/FIN,SYN /* pscan 2 */
8        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,RST/FIN,RST /* pscan 3 */
9        2   104 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN,RST /* SYN-RST scan */
10       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:ACK,URG/URG /* URG scan */
11       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN /* SYN-FIN scan */
12       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,PSH,URG /* nmap Xmas scan */
13       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN /* FIN scan */
14       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,PSH,URG /* nmap-id scan */
15       0     0 DROP       all  -f  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* fragmented packets */
16    5049 1668K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID /* invalid packets */
17    1358  795K REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN /* new non-syn packets */ reject-with tcp-reset
18      52  2600 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere             /* loopback: compulsory */
19    2588  303K ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request limit: avg 2/sec burst 5 /* ICMP: ping only */
20   15482  932K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:57329 /* SSH: global obfuscated */
21     97M   54G ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9001 /* Tor: OR */
22   54303 4010K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9030 /* Tor: Dir */
23     95M   93G ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* Tor: traffic */

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 182M packets, 160G bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

For me, what comes to mind, is possibly DHCP packets, but I do not know much about this, so...

I don't personally do networking, so I'd appreciate if anyone could help with this. Thanks.

---

Edits:

- #1: My server is a **DHCP client**.
- #2: I just changed ICMP policy to REJECT (reject-with **icmp-admin-prohibited**), and it did not affect my server getting a static lease (upon reboot).

Answer (score 1):

Any DHCP client needs to use RAW sockets on Linux, as it needs to send packets with 0.0.0.0 as source address (which is not normally allowed) until it gets a real IP address from a DHCP server.

As a side effect, it completely bypasses iptables filters - *if* you are running the DHCP client on the system that is doing the filtering. If your system is not acting as a bridge or router for other hosts, you can ignore the UDP requirements of DHCP.

But for the sake of knowledge, or if you are using some other firewalling solution: if you are a DHCP client, then you'll need to accept incoming UDP packets for port 68. In theory, these packets should have a source port number of 67. A DHCP server may also want to ping your IP address.

One thing to note with DHCP is that the packets might be arriving using the local network's broadcast address or 255.255.255.255 as the destination address while you don't yet have a valid IP address of your own. After the initial DHCP lease has been acquired, the renewals may be regular unicasts.

If you are a DHCP server, you should accept incoming UDP packets for port 67.

Another possible user of UDP is DNS. A DNS query can be sent out using UDP for speed, and if the response is too large to fit in a single UDP packet, the DNS server will send in UDP as much of the answer that fits in the packet, with an added attribute that means "re-submit query over TCP if you want the full answer".

NTP (Network Time Protocol) also uses UDP (port number 123). When the message content is essentially "at the moment this packet was sent, the time was xx:xx:xx.xxxxxx... as accurately as I could determine", using TCP with its handshakes and potential retransmissions makes no sense. If a time signal is lost in transit, you don't ask the old signal to be re-transmitted, but request (or wait for) a new one.

Comment: @A.B So even if I completely disabled UDP(v4), it should be fine?